# Access: count how many time an item is used

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables:

The table `Consent Archiving` is a list of unique items.

The table `Table1` is the association of n rows to 1 item of `Consent Archiving`.

I would like that in the column `Count` of `Consent Archiving` there would be the number of time that that certain item is repeated into `Table1`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want the number to be stored in the table as a value? It would seem better to retrieve it just using a query whenever needed (something like Select table1."Consent Archiving", count(*) From table1 Group by table1."Consent Archiving"). If you wanted to actually store the value, you'd have to update the table by some trigger.

Comment: well I need it because I use "Consent Archiving" in a subform where I would like to have the list and the count for each item.

Comment: how about creating a "view" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836312.aspx)? It behaves as a table, but the content changes according to the defined sql query within

Comment: Don't store the value in the table. Base the subform off of a query that does the count...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't a query, build to look like mentioned table, a better option? If so build it on Table1 and just add group by clause for "Consent Archiving" with a count(*) function.